# Powershell: Replace current directory path in text file, with nothing (using batch file)

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch

I have a batch file and a text file in a folder.

The text file contains lines with the path to the current folder where that text file resides.

I want to replace the instances of the current directory's path in the text file, with nothing.

Because it's powershell, using `%~dp0` doesn't work:

```
-replace '%~dp0', ''
```

I expected it not to and I looked up what the equivalent to `%~dp0` is in Powershell (v3+) and found that it's `$PSScriptRoot` but running this in my powershell command isn't working, the path to the current folder still remains in the text file:

```
-replace '$PSScriptRoot', ''
```

I also read that `$currentScriptPath` was used prior to powershell v3 so I tried that:

```
-replace '$currentScriptPath', ''
```

Also not working.

**Edit:** Tried leaving the single quotes out, not working:

```
-replace $PSScriptRoot
```

Tried this - not working (with other parts of the command changed to single quotes as opposed to double quotes, to account for this part now using double quotes - but I know from doing that in the past on other powershell commands run from batch files, it stops the command working)

```
-Replace $PSScriptRoot,""
```

Tried this, not working...

```
-replace $PSScriptRoot, ''
```

*(with other parts of the command put back how they were with double quotes)*

I guess it's not working because I am not running the powershell command in `.ps1` script?

Is it possible to keep this command in a batch file and replace the path in the text file with powershell?

Cheers.

Comment: OK, let's see if I've got this straight: You're doing most of the work, including the ROBOCOPY, in Batch, and are sending the ROBOCOPY output to a text file, which you want to process with PowerShell to remove the undesired path information? And then what: write it back out to the file, or just dump it to the console?

Comment: When will you finally take our advice that we told you for about your last 8 questions, and use PowerShell on its own instead of in batch files? I do really not understand why you do this. This just complicates stuff. Writing this question alone takes more time than understanding how to call PowerShell directly. Concerning this question use `-replace [regex]::escape((get-location).path)` - however it might be that you run into issues, since PowerShells current path might be different than cmd's current path.

Comment: `-replace` uses RegEx. a path contains characters that have special meaning in regex you need to escape like @Balthazar commented. You say that you've tried different things, but all your code lines do not deal with this, and some lines even **single-quote** variables, making them literal text...

Comment: Jeff Zeitlin, yes I am only trying to hide the path to the current directory, in the command window. @Balthazar, I don't use ps1 scripts because they don't even open by default with Powershell (unlike a batch file that just runs with cmd.exe). Also there's different variables in Powershell, depending on whether it's before or after version 3. Thirdly you said yourself "however it might be that you run into issues, since PowerShells current path might be different than cmd's current path" - this wouldn't matter in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell doesn't evaluate variables in strings enclosed by single quotes. Use double quotes instead, or if the variable contains the entire string you want to use, and only that, don't bother to quote it at all:

```
$string_containing_filename_with_complete_path -replace $PSScriptRoot,""
```

Comment: If this is connected with your ROBOCOPY question, you want to use `(ROBOCOPY...) | ForEach-Object { $_ -Replace $PSScriptRoot,"" }`. You may not need the `()` parens, but I'm not _absolutely_ certain on that.

Comment: It sort of is but this is a separate question just to use a powershell command to replace the current directory's path in the log file being outputted by robocopy. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry it's not working, I'll edit what else I tried into the question.